# Commands ignored until end of transaction block in GeoDjango when creating PostGIS spatial database template

Tags: django, transactions, geospatial, postgresql-9.1, postgis

Am trying to create a spatial database template using the this  [Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/#spatialdb-template-earlier) , but when it comes to the point to execute the commands from the files against the database (`$ psql -d template_postgis -f $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH/postgis.sql`) it always brings me stuff like this:
 `“template_postgis2=# \i /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql:6056: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ROLLBACK”`
Nothing changes then so far..
Any hint what could be wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PostgreSQL 9.1 with PostGIS 2.1, there is no need to create a template for spatial databases. Just use `CREATE EXTENSION` to spatially enable your database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Note that there should already be a `template_postgis_20` template available once you have installed the PostGIS 2.1 package, so you can enable the PostGIS extension at once when creating a new DB:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb TEMPLATE template_postgis_20;
```

This has the exact same effect as creating a blank DB (using the default template1 database template) then running the `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I run CREATE EXTENSION postgis;,
 I get ERROR: could not open extension control file "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.1/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P0.